# SQL Server statement incorrect syntax near right?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a statement like this:

```
SELECT  
    TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_ID,
    TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_NAME,
    TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK 
        WHERE TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK.LINK_ID = 1)
FROM TBL_CS_LINKS
join right TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK 
    on TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_ID = TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK.LINK_ID
WHERE 
    (CHARINDEX('s', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0) OR  
    (CHARINDEX('s', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_NAME) > 0) 
order by   TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_NAME
```

and it gives me an error :

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'right'.*

What could be the problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you got the keywords in the wrong order.

It's

```
right join
left join
```

or

```
right outer join
left outer join
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used the right keyword incorrectly. Please check below for the proper use of it

```
SELECT  TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_ID,
        TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_NAME,
        TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK WHERE TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK.LINK_ID = 1)
FROM TBL_CS_LINKS
right join TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK 
on TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_ID = TBL_CS_TEMP_CLICK.LINK_ID

WHERE  (CHARINDEX('s', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0) OR  
       (CHARINDEX('s', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_NAME) > 0) 
order by   TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_NAME
```